# Button height in fraction

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to have button size in fractions?

I want the height to be specified as 23.7, but when I run the app and check the actual height, it is rounded to 24. The height and width are of type double so I expected it to take and honor the fractional values, but for some reason it is rounding up.

Is it possible to have fractional height with some settings/hack?

```
<Button 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Margin="0,12,0,0" 
    Width="80"
    Height="23.7" 
    Content="Market"
    Command="{Binding OrderSellMarketButtonCommand}"/>
```

I even tried binding the Height to VM property of type double. That did not help either.

Screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the fraction?

Comment: To align the button to something else which is already present and not under my control.

Comment: If it is just for alignment, why not use the container (Grid?) and VerticalAlignment attribute to line them out? Alternatively you could bind its height to the height of the other control.

Comment: it is a chart and I have to align the button to the index on the y-axis. The chart is 3rd party. The grid/VA is not helping me here. Thanks.

Comment: I can't imagine how a fraction would fail to align the control by more than one pixel unless you are trying to handle DPI settings other than 96. Even in that case multiply by the screen's DPI and round off and you should be one pixel off at most.

Comment: I am not handling the DPI setting. I did not understand your next suggestion about multiplication.

Comment: You do not have to 'handle DPI' in order to be affected by it. I am sorry, your problem and question are not clear. It looks like you are trying to solve a problem that does not exist using a solution that is no solution. If you want valuable, actual answers we need code that will actually present the problem.

Comment: I am very thankful to you that you are trying to help me. Problem/Question is simple - can I have the height in fraction?. if you know and have used such heights please help me. 
I answered your questions on why I need such height. if you are still not convinced why I need such height then I dont know what to say. 
You are only confusing me about DPIs, sometimes you say I am setting them and next reply is dont have to set them to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

The double type is slightly misleading in that case, because the actual size of the control depends on the currently set DPI value. Normally, at 100% the DPI value is 96 and since the default WPF measuring unit is a device independent pixel (which is 1/96 inch) it maps to whole pixels which aren't fractions.

It's a bit strange that you want to align something in the sub-pixel range, can you maybe show us an example or screenshot?

Edit: After seeing you screenshot, it looks like that the text in the middle has a slightly larger fontsize than the buttons. If it's acceptable, you can up the fontsize on the button by one:

```
<Button 
  Grid.Column="0" 
  Margin="0,12,0,0" 
  Width="80"
  Height="23"     
  Command="{Binding OrderSellMarketButtonCommand}">
   <Button.Content>
     <TextBlock Text="Market" FontSize="13"/>
   </Button.Content>
  </Button>
```

Comment: How can I post an image here?, the only way now I can think of is putting on my googledrive and give you access. if there are other ways please let me know - thanks

Comment: @SubhashBadri You may need 10 reputation to upload an image here directly (I don't know if the 10 rep limit still exists). If yes, just upload it to imgur and put the link in the question, someone will correctly put it in. Otherwise see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/171426

Comment: @SubhashBadri Added the image to your question. See my edited answer.

Comment: Tried that option but no success.it works for 23,25 but not 23.x

Comment: Yes, that doesn't change the fact that you can't use fractions, just that the fonts look aligned, my fault.

Answer (score -1):

Layout is complex in WPF. i put here a translation of a training slide.

Since WPF is completely independent of resolution, the prerequisite is never to specify sizes or coordinates so that the layout of the elements works regardless of the resolution or size of the screen.

The layout management process is based on the following principle:
That each element (a potential container) intervenes
That every container, for all these children

- Demands their "desired" size
- Then arranges them according to his "model" of organization

These 2 main methods are available in the Panel and are overloadable when creating custom controls and containers

- MeasureOverride
- ArrangeOverride

This means you will have no chance to get the values you put in Width and Height into the real ActualWidth and ActualHeight - Or you have a complete fixed layout but that will not fit with "independent of resolution"